# Django PostUpdateView isn't saving image ValueError thrown

Tags: python, django, imagefield

In models.py I have:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post_content = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    date_posted= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog-post-images/', blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 500 or img.width > 500:
            if img.height > img.width:
                factor=500/img.height
                nH=500
                nW=img.width*factor
                output_size= (nH,nW)
            if img.width > img.height:
                factor=500/img.width
                nW=500
                nH=img.height*factor
                output_size= (nH,nW)
            else:
                output_size=(500,500)
            img = ImageOps.exif_transpose(img)
        
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

And then in views I have:

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'post_content', 'image'] 
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    def test_func(self):
        post=self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False
```

Upon runserver, page renders html with form fields just fine, allows me to select image path, but then the error I get thrown when actually submitting image path is:
"ValueError at /home/post/10/update/
The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it."
And image doesn't save. However, when I do it through admin it does save image.
I have image blank and null bc I want image to be optional attribute. Is this the reason I'm getting issues? Does something extra need to be added to PostUpdateView class?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question.

All it required was adding enctype="multipart/dorm-data" to form tag to html file:

```
<form method="POST" class="form-parent" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```